# Edit HTML files permanently with PHP

Tags: php

I am building a blogging website and I am facing troubles when I try to upload a photo. I need the photo to be pasted in the webpage. I know that javascript can do that, but it only affects the current session of the webpage. I need to permanently embed that image into the webpage as a child of this div element, for example:

```
<div id="img-wrapper"></div>
```

Everything is OK with PHP file uploads. How can I do that with PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume its not an advisable solution as it increases the page size, but you can do this in the following manner:-

Some examples:

HTML:

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

CSS:

```
div.image {
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background-image:url(data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA...);
}
```

Here is a sample code

https://jsfiddle.net/casiano/xadvz/

For an online image to base 64 encode [Click here](http://www.greywyvern.com/code/php/binary2base64)